# HTTPS not working with self signed certificate in tomcat

Tags: tomcat7

I am new to https configuration in tomcat. I googled a lot but that did not solve my  problem.
I have an ec2 machine and tomcat deployed on it. I tried to create self signed certificate , which was easy to generate.I used my domain www.test.com(changed test with my server name) and keystore file was generated. Then I edited conf/server.xml for https configuration as described in ssl howto of tomcat docs.But https is not working. Though when I do "curl https:// localhost :8443 -k " I can get response but it is not working in browser. Takes to long to respond and boom I am done with nothing. Do I need a certificate or It will work with keystore file only? Please tell me .
Please help me out
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Thanks for you answer, I found my issue and would like explain my resolution
1.) Curl was working but it was not responding in browser . I had to open port 8443 manually from security groups in aws. It was working then :).

2.) For all others if they face with the problem "Failed to establish chain from reply"
i) please check your keystore file. Is it the same used to generate CSR?
ii) Install intermediate certificates provided by your certificate authority.
For some of them you can follow
https://www.sslcertificaten.nl/download/Root_Certificaten/
use alias primary and secondary respectively
**$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -alias primary -keystore sslkey -trustcacerts -file primary_cert.crt -storepass mypass**

**$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -alias secondary -keystore sslkey -trustcacerts -file secondary_cert.crt -storepass mypass**
iii) finally import your certificate
**$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore sslkey -trustcacerts -file www_mydomain_com.p7b -storepass mypass**

Hope this helps
cheers

Answer (score 0):

If `curl` works, then the problem is either in the browser or in the servlet - SSL setup should be correct. Check the log files of Tomcat for errors and set breakpoints in your servlets to see what happens.